# Where is the display window in Android studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

eclipse has display tool(window -> show view) in debug, I want to call variable or method name like eclipse  so where is the display tool in android studio ??

please help, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the 'Evaluate Expression' window, which pops up with a ALT+F8 combo. [Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html) is some more info.

Comment: I'm trying to get used to the android studio, it is cool thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes "Evaluate Expression" in Android studio is like the "Display view" in eclipse. In case you're not sure of the shortcut, Go to  Run > Evaluate Expression.

Hope that helps